# jQuery .focus doesn’t actually focus a newly created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

Let’s say I have this markup:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="firstP"><p>First paragraph</p></div>
  <div id="secondP"><p>Second paragraph</p></div>
  <div id="thirdP"><p>Third paragraph</p></div>
  <div id="fourthP"><p>Fourth paragraph</p></div>
</div>
```

I want to add a new `<div>` with jQuery and focus on this new element. `.focus` does not do anything.

```
function addParagraph() {
  var html = "<div id=\"newP\"><p>New paragraph</p></div>";

  $("#content").append(html);
  $("#newP").focus();    
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 50):

I think the main answer is incorrect. DIV and P tags can receive focus providing you specify a tabindex property for them. i.e.

```
<div class="someclass" tabindex="100">
```

Once the tabindex is specified you can either tab to these elements or shift focus with *.focus()* .

Using a scrollTo plugin seems like a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: This helped me figure out how to process some keyboard commands in a tree container div. By assigning a keypress event handler to a div with a tabIndex value, I was able to add keyboard commands to a hierarchical data editor.

Comment: Perfect! Yours is the best solution in terms of being simple. I like simple stuff. I prefer to avoid a script if it can be done without it.

Comment: You should use tabindex="0" if you don't want to disturb the order of the tabs in the page. If you only want to give focus with Javascript, and make the div not focusable, put tabindex="-1". Tabindex -1 can receive focus by Javascript, but not by hitting the tab key.

Answer (score 17):

There's no problem with your code, it's just that **a paragraph or div tag can't receive focus**. Focus can only be given to things you can interact with, such as links, input elements, textareas, etc.

To scroll the window to this newly added element, you can use a plugin such as [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).

On a side note, your code could be simplified a bit:

```
var html = "<div id=\"newP\"><p>New paragraph</p></div>";
$("#content").append(html);
$("#newP p").focus();

var html = "<div id=\"newP\"><p>New paragraph</p></div>";
$(html)
    .appendTo('#content')
    .focus()   // or scrollTo(), now...
;
```

Comment: No need to append to $('#content'), just appendTo('#content')

Comment: thanks, edited - though i suppose that behind the scenes it does the exact same thing...

Answer (score 6):

This code will avoid dependencies on other plugins and allow you to have it on any element.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#newP").offset().top }, 500);
```

Comment: Nice idea. I used this rather than a new plugin and just set the timeout to 0. Wonder if I should wrap that up in a function and call it ScrollTo...

Comment: Yeah you could do that and just have a variable for the #newP so you could focus any element on event.

Comment: So much better than use another plugin! GREAT!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a HTML page anchor not focus. Example:

```
http://localhost/mypage.html#fourthP
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is using the 'ScrollTo' plugin in jQuery.  You can [check it out here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html).

You can specify what to scroll...

```
$('div.pane').scrollTo(...);//all divs w/class pane
```

Or just scroll the window:

```
$.scrollTo(...);//the plugin will take care of this
```

There are many different ways to specify the target position.
These are:

- A raw number
- A string('44', '100px', '+=30px',
  etc )
- A DOM element (logically, child of
  the scrollable element)
- A selector, that will be relative to
  the scrollable element
- A hash { top:x, left:y }, x and y
  can be any kind of number/string
  like above.

**Bonus:**
In digging up this information, I also found [LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) and [SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) (animates scrolling from one item to the next).

Answer (score 1):

Only form elements and such can attain focus. If you want the browser to scroll down to that particular paragraph, there is no "default" way of doing so with jQuery, but there is a plugin for it at [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and a blog explaining how to do it manually at [Animated scroll with jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$("#newP").focus();
```

it should be used:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href + "#newP";
```

Comment: it may need tabindex property.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign tabidex and then you can set focus to that element

```
$('#table').attr("tabindex",1).focus();
```

This will work for Div Table etc which can't get focus by itself.