# Getting focus on a Div

Tags: javascript, html

Does there exist some trick other than **tabindex attribute** so that a div can get focus ?

Comment: Why do you want to give focus to a div element?

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334489/jquery-focus

Comment: I am using a div as an editor (not as a text editor ). It will contain various small images which should listen some keyboard events when parent div'll be selected

Comment: I'm not sure focusing a `div` will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `contenteditable="true"` will also allow a div to receive focus in browsers that support it (IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.0+, WebKit for a few years, not sure about Opera), though obviously with the side effect of making the div editable by the user.

```
<div contenteditable="true">Tab to me</div>
```