# Webkit does not appear to support $.focus() on layers and IE9 does. Anyway to get webkit browsers to do so too?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See the fiddle below. Both focus events will fire in IE and only
the one for the input will work in webkit browsers and firefox.

I require .focus() on layers because in my page there are controls
that are enabled and disabled depending on whether the user clicks on
the control bar or the white space below which is a layer. Using something
like .click() won't cut it since the event fires every time I click on any
link/text over said white space, strangely also only in non IE browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Pxw/11/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the best rated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334489/jquery-focus) a `div` cannot get focus unless it has a `tabindex` attribute.  As far as I understand, this contradicts HTML 4.01 but works...

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the jQuery code. It may do what you want to do actually.

http://jsfiddle.net/X2Pxw/20/